# Error in VSCode when starting React projects using NX console

Tags: reactjs, vscode-extensions, nx-monorepo

I have a simple monorepo with two projects created: catalog and check-out

**Run the app locally**

Click on the Nx Console icon (in VSCode) and then, under GENERATE & RUN TARGET, select serve and then, from the dropdown at the top, select the catalog app, then select Execute:nx run catalog:serve.

However, immediately when selecting the `catalog app`, I get the **error in VSCode** "*Builder specified for catalog serve was not found in your dependencies. Check that specified builder is correct and has a corresponding entry in package.json*"

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "micro-fe",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nx serve",
    "build": "nx build",
    "test": "nx test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "0.13.7",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nrwl/cli": "14.8.9",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "14.8.9",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "14.8.9",
    "@nrwl/jest": "14.8.9",
    "@nrwl/linter": "14.8.9",
    "@nrwl/react": "14.8.9",
    "@nrwl/web": "14.8.9",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "14.8.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "13.4.0",
    "@types/jest": "28.1.1",
    "@types/node": "16.11.7",
    "@types/react": "18.0.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.36.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.36.1",
    "babel-jest": "28.1.1",
    "cypress": "^10.7.0",
    "eslint": "~8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.31.8",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.6.0",
    "jest": "28.1.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "28.1.1",
    "nx": "14.8.9",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "ts-jest": "28.0.5",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2"
  }
}
```

Then, I just ran the application using `npx nx serve catalog` with the following successful output:

```
> nx run catalog:serve:development

<i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:4200/, http://[::1]:4200/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] 404s will fallback to '/index.html'

>  NX  Web Development Server is listening at http://localhost:4200/

Entrypoint main [big] 1.63 MiB (1.93 MiB) = runtime.js 50.8 KiB vendor.js 1.52 MiB main.js 57.7 KiB 3 auxiEntrypoint main [big] 1.63 MiB (1.93 MiB) = runtime.js 50.8 KiB vendor.js 1.52 MiB main.js 57.7 KiB 3 auxiliary assets
Entrypoint polyfills [big] 822 KiB (1020 KiB) = runtime.js 50.8 KiB polyfills.js 771 KiB 2 auxiliary assets
Entrypoint styles [big] 460 KiB (577 KiB) = runtime.js 50.8 KiB styles.css 399 bytes styles.js 409 KiB 2 auxiliary assets
chunk (runtime: runtime) main.js (main) 49.5 KiB [initial] [rendered]
chunk (runtime: runtime) polyfills.js (polyfills) 719 KiB [initial] [rendered]
chunk (runtime: runtime) runtime.js (runtime) 34.2 KiB [entry] [rendered]
chunk (runtime: runtime) styles.css, styles.js (styles) 389 KiB (javascript) 398 bytes (css/mini-extract) [initial] [rendered]
chunk (runtime: runtime) vendor.js (vendor) (id hint: vendor) 1.5 MiB [initial] [rendered] split chunk (cache group: vendor) (name: vendor)
webpack compiled successfully (6caaee5c77a18f4d)
No errors found.
```

I was able to run the check-out project, after including a different port (4300) in project.json under serve to avoid address already in use ::1:4200

I can start both projects as explained above. I have the NX Console installed in VSCode. I am able to see the NX View including PROJECTS, GENERATE & RUN TARGET, COMMON NX COMMANDS. However, when following the steps explained at the beginning I am getting an error.

I would like to know what is the fix to avoid the error in VSCode.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem before, check if you have a workplace.json file in workpalce.

Otherwise, download code the author provided in book to test if you have configured vs code in the right way.